# Probit and logit Model

Tags: econometrics

Can you provide me with an intuition about what it means to derive a probit or logit model from an underlying latent variable model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logit and probit models can be derived from an underlying latent variable model. To see this, let $y^{\ast}$ be an unobserved (i.e. latent) variable, and suppose that
\begin{equation}
    y^{\ast} = \beta_0 + x\beta + \epsilon, ~y=1[y^{\ast}>\gamma]
    \label{latent}
\end{equation}
where $1[\cdot]$ is an indicator function taking value $1$ if $y^{\ast}>\gamma$ and zero otherwise. Here, $\gamma$ is a chosen threshold. If the latent unobserved utility $y^\ast$ is above the threshold, then $y$ takes the value one; otherwise, it takes the value zero.

The idea is to see the binary outcome $y=\{0,1 \}$ as a dichotomization of a latent continuous variable $y^{\ast}$ modeled with a canonical multiple linear regression model. For example, a bank can issue a loan ($y=1$) or choose not to ($y=0$). Think of it as having an underlying continuous latent outcome, $y^{\ast}$ which can be regarded as a measure of the choice utility.

In the model above, we assume that $\epsilon$ is independent of $x$ and that $\epsilon$ either has the standard logistic distribution or the standard normal distribution.

Recall, the standard logistic and standard normal distribution are symmetric about zero. Thus, $1-G(-z)=G(z)$.

From the model above, we can derive the response probability for $y$. First, we assumed that $y_i=1$ if and only if $y^{\ast}_i > \gamma$, with $\gamma$ set arbitrarily to zero. Thus,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(y=1|x) =& \mathbb{P}(y^{\ast} >0|x) = \mathbb{P}(\beta_0 + x\beta + \epsilon >0|x) = \\
    =&\mathbb{P}[ \epsilon > -(\beta_0 + x\beta ) |x] =1 - \mathbb{P}[ \epsilon \le -(\beta_0 + x\beta ) |x] \\
    =& 1 - G[ - (\beta_0 + x\beta)] = G(\beta_0 + x \beta)
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{P}[ \epsilon \le -(\beta_0 + x\beta ) |x]$ is the cdf of the error term of the latent outcome.